# How to wait for GET Request with Axios to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, get-request

I am making a Web-Notepad using Nodejs and express where all the data is gonna be saved in MongoDB. I want to grab the data through my Rest API making an HTTP request with Axion.

When I send the GET request, the program doesn't wait for the JSON file, continues and because of that, it exports an undefined file with the site is getting shown without the data.

With the console.log after the GET request, I get all the data I need - but too late.

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const debug = require('debug')('app');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv/config')

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts');
// Here i import the data from the GET request
const getData = require('./routes/router');

app.use('/posts', postsRoute);

// The outcome of this log is; Promise {<pending>}
console.log(getData);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render(
        'index',
        {
// Here i want to send the Data to the ejs file
            getData,
            title: 'Notepad'
        });
});

// Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
    {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false}, () =>
        debug('Connected correctly to MongoDB')
);

app.listen(port, () => {
    debug(`Listening on port ${chalk.green(port)}`);
});
```

router.js where i make the GET request (i should change the name of the file...)

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

async function getData() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/posts');
        console.log(response);
        return response.data
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

module.exports = getData();
```

GET Request:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const posts = await post.find();
        res.json(posts);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err})
    }
});
```

Comment: Your router.js file exports a promise. To get the data out of a promise, you call then() - or await it. What's the confusion?

Comment: Oh damn! That explained it... Had to call then() in the app.js file.
Sorry, i am still pretty new to this topic.. 
And Thank you!